# Where within the Internet Explorer installation files can I find the browser error pages?

Tags: microsoft

Is it possible find the default error pages (e.g., bad request, forbidden, not found, gateway timeout, etc.) for Internet Explorer within the installation files or even the Windows 98 CD?

I'm thinking of pages such as this one:

[image: "Cannot find server" page in Internet Explorer]

Comment: I tried taking a more time-appropriate screenshot and… it seems IE4 did not *have* those pages yet.

Comment: <https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2JEx.png>: no error pages, just a message box.

Comment: Didn’t Second Edition ship with IE5? Because I remember that one had error pages.

Comment: @user3840170 that’s right, and my answer was based on 98SE — I didn’t think to check the version of IE at the time, but it’s IE5.

Comment: @AlexHajnal I presume they were flagged as ‘no longer needed’ after Stephen’s answer was posted and the screenshot added to the question.

Comment: @user3840170 It's a shame since they brought up some salient points not mentioned in the question or answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Internet Explorer 5 (which is the first release with pages in the style shown in your screenshot), the error pages are stored as resources in `SHDOCLC.DLL`, which is shipped in `WIN98_41.CAB` on my Windows 98 SE CD; `wrestool` shows

```
--type=23 --name='ABOUT.DLG' --language=1033 [offset=0x26300 size=5098]
--type=23 --name='ANALYZE.DLG' --language=1033 [offset=0x34de8 size=8651]
--type=23 --name='ANCHRPPG.PPG' --language=1033 [offset=0x31108 size=2463]
--type=23 --name='BIDIFIND.DLG' --language=1033 [offset=0x2d908 size=8433]
--type=23 --name='DNSERROR.HTM' --language=1033 [offset=0x429e8 size=3726]
--type=23 --name='DOCPPG.PPG' --language=1033 [offset=0x33518 size=5226]
--type=23 --name='ERROR.DLG' --language=1033 [offset=0x276f0 size=4824]
--type=23 --name='FIND.DLG' --language=1033 [offset=0x2fa00 size=5894]
--type=23 --name='FINDINC.DLG' --language=1033 [offset=0x2be80 size=6789]
--type=23 --name='HTTP_400.HTM' --language=1033 [offset=0x3ace0 size=3715]
--type=23 --name='HTTP_403.HTM' --language=1033 [offset=0x3bb68 size=3493]
--type=23 --name='HTTP_404.HTM' --language=1033 [offset=0x3c910 size=3704]
--type=23 --name='HTTP_406.HTM' --language=1033 [offset=0x3d788 size=1928]
--type=23 --name='HTTP_410.HTM' --language=1033 [offset=0x3df10 size=3280]
--type=23 --name='HTTP_500.HTM' --language=1033 [offset=0x3ebe0 size=4842]
--type=23 --name='HTTP_501.HTM' --language=1033 [offset=0x3fed0 size=4821]
--type=23 --name='HTTP_GEN.HTM' --language=1033 [offset=0x411a8 size=4529]
--type=23 --name='IEERROR.DLG' --language=1033 [offset=0x289c8 size=9400]
--type=23 --name='IMAGE.GIF' --language=1033 [offset=0x33098 size=1149]
--type=23 --name='IMAGEPPG.PPG' --language=1033 [offset=0x31f80 size=4370]
--type=23 --name='LINK.GIF' --language=1033 [offset=0x31aa8 size=1239]
--type=23 --name='ORGFAV.DLG' --language=1033 [offset=0x445d8 size=10359]
--type=23 --name='PAGE.GIF' --language=1033 [offset=0x34988 size=1120]
--type=23 --name='PRINTERR.HTM' --language=1033 [offset=0x46e50 size=341]
--type=23 --name='PRINTNF.HTM' --language=1033 [offset=0x46fa8 size=179]
--type=23 --name='PRINTUNK.HTM' --language=1033 [offset=0x47060 size=183]
--type=23 --name='SERVBUSY.HTM' --language=1033 [offset=0x42360 size=1671]
--type=23 --name='SYNTAX.HTM' --language=1033 [offset=0x43878 size=3417]
--type=23 --name='WCEE.HTM' --language=1033 [offset=0x36fb8 size=15655]
```

(among many others). Resource type 23 is “[HTML resource](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resource-types)”.

All the resources can be extracted using `wrestool` or any other resource extraction tool, and the corresponding pages viewed using any browser; here’s Firefox showing Internet Explorer 5’s DNS error page (the same one used in your screenshot):

[image: Firefox showing Internet Explorer 5’s DNS error page]

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I was just saddened to discover my original Windows 98 SE disc is corrupted (even before I created my image backup file), specifically on all of the `WIN_XX.CAB` files, but I was able to discover, shall we say, other sources...

Comment: The screenshot in the question depicts Windows XP, which I think shipped with IE6… although I think the error pages were identical to the IE5 ones, so I guess it’s still correct.

Comment: @user3840170 good point, I’ve rephrased accordingly.